# Qt: Expand ~ to home-directory

Tags: qt, path, expansion, tilde

Does Qt have any platform-independent functionality to accept paths like "~/myfile"?

I know about [wordexp](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/wordexp.html), but it would be nice with a platform-independent wrapper.

**Edit:**

Thank you all for the responses. "~/myfile" was just an example. What I am looking for is functionality to handle file-paths as you would be able to write on the command-line. So on Linux, it should accept "~/myfile", "~otheruser/hisfile", "$VAR/file" etc. On Windows, it should accept "%HOMEDIR%\myfile" etc.

Answer (score 13):

You could probably just replace the tilde with the result of `QDir::homePath()`? Reference [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#homePath).

Comment: But _only_ if the `~` is at the beginning.

Comment: You should ensure that it's only done when the ~ is at the start of the path and followed by a path separator.  There's also the issue of paths like "~foo/myfile" which should expand to myfile under foo's home.  Not sure how easy that would be to handle outside of a *nix environment where it's trivial to query another user's home directory.

Answer (score -3):

I think that the absolutePath (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#absolutePath) is the way to do it.

Comment: There's no mention of tilde expansion in the documentation.